# How to train DDQN model in reinforcement learning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I was reading through [some RL code](https://github.com/germain-hug/Deep-RL-Keras/blob/master/DDQN/ddqn.py#L65) but couldn't understand one small bit.

here is the code:

```
# Apply Bellman Equation on batch samples to train our DDQN
    q = self.agent.predict(s)
    next_q = self.agent.predict(new_s)
    q_targ = self.agent.target_predict(new_s)

    for i in range(s.shape[0]):
        old_q = q[i, a[i]]
        if d[i]:
            q[i, a[i]] = r[i]
        else:
            next_best_action = np.argmax(next_q[i,:])
            q[i, a[i]] = r[i] + self.gamma * q_targ[i, next_best_action]
        if(self.with_per):
            # Update PER Sum Tree
            self.buffer.update(idx[i], abs(old_q - q[i, a[i]]))
    # Train on batch
    self.agent.fit(s, q)
    # Decay epsilon
    self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
```

From my understanding, the Q function maps (state, action) pairs to rewards. However in the code above you assume that the Agent networks to return Q values. However a quick inspection of the [Agent model](https://github.com/germain-hug/Deep-RL-Keras/blob/master/DDQN/agent.py), reveals that it actually returns actions, which makes sense since that's what the agent has to learn. Rewards are be calculated within env.step(action). So then, in the belmann equation we find this addition `r[i] + self.gamma * q_targ[i, next_best_action]`.
Isn't `q_targ[i, next_best_action]` an action? so how can it be added to a reward?

Comment: The code for `target_predict` clearly returns an array of values from the NN, not an *action* - https://github.com/germain-hug/Deep-RL-Keras/blob/master/DDQN/agent.py#L76-L79 - where are you seeing that it returns actions?

Comment: just because the output layer of the model's NN is defined as a representation of the action space. But in fact the predict is being run on a batch of states, so it will return a set of actions.

Comment: OK. You have got that part wrong on your "quick inspection". The NN output matches the action space because for each action it predicts the action-value (not the reward, but the expected sum of discounted future rewards). If that explains things to you, then good. Otherwise could you expand on what you noticed in the "quick inspection" and why you think the agent is learning actions (it isn't, at least not directly) - and I will try to explain in more detail in an answer.

Comment: @NeilSlater, Thanks. Now I see that. since the action space is discrete, learning the action value, gives you the action for free as the action with maximum value.

Comment: That's *sort of* correct. This is about how Q-learning and the q function works. The `argmax` necessary to pick (hopefully) the best action is sadly not free, and you notice that when the action space becomes large. Some agents might bundle that decision making into a method call but that does not seem to be the case here). Other types of RL agent, based on policy functions, might have a very similar-looking network that really does output an action.